# Huge text file processing in linux

Tags: bash, text

I have a huge text file like this (at least 1000000 lines):

```
1.1.1.1.10001  2.2.2.2.80
3.3.3.3.53  4.4.4.4.23456
5.5.5.5  6.6.6.6
7.7.7.7.45329  8.8.8.8.443
```

what's the best and fastest logic you will do to delete the line with valid IP addresses in both columns? For the above input, line to be removed is

```
5.5.5.5  6.6.6.6
```

Comment: I would write a C program (or a Rust one, or a C++ one, or at least Python or Ocaml) to process that file. Otherwise use `awk`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56536624/edit) your question. You want at least the example lines to be given as code chunk, so four spaces before every line

Comment: Remove tag [*processing*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info). [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Comment: Also, define *exactly* what is a valid IP address for you. I can't think of any obvious definition (a `ping`-able address, or something known to the DNS, or something answering to HTTP requests, ???) Without that, **your question is unclear**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your given example, I will assume that your definition of "valid IP address" simply precludes the port designation. In lieu of a more detailed question, please note that this command will remove `456.789.123.456`, which is not valid IPv4.

```
$ awk -v re='^([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+$' '$1!~re && $2!~re' file
1.1.1.1.10001  2.2.2.2.80
3.3.3.3.53  4.4.4.4.23456
7.7.7.7.45329  8.8.8.8.443
```